# 'Object does not have geometry data' error when running headless?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, export, geometry

I have the following blender python script:

```py
import bpy
from random import randint

#how many cubes you want to add
count = 10

for c in range(0,count):
    x = randint(-10,10)
    y = randint(-10,10)
    z = randint(-10,10)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(x,y,z))
    print(f'Cube added at coordinates: {x}{y}{z}')
    
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath="C://Users//diego//OneDrive//CFD//output.stl")
```

And it works perfectly when called by `blender --python script.py`
but fails when called by `blender -b --python script.py`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data

Blender quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not happen if you don't have the default cube/light/camera in your startup file (I don't know why). So putting this at the start of your script to remove all objects

```
while bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects[0], do_unlink=True)
```

appears to fix it.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

It makes sense that those were the two objects without geometry, but the fact that it worked with the ui really misled me

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from https://docs.blender.org/api/242PythonDoc/API_related-module.html :

```
Background mode examples:
# Open Blender in background mode with file 'myfile.blend'
# and run the script 'script.py':

blender -b myfile.blend -P script.py

# Note: a .blend file is always required.  'script.py' can be a file
# in the file system or a Blender Text stored in 'myfile.blend'.
```

I have tested it but you can try adding a file in your command line options

Comment: Those docs are from 2.42, released in 2006. A .blend is definitely not required in modern Blender. But it doesn't hurt to try I guess...

Comment: I've tried using a .blend file (saved the default cube scene, and even deleting the cube) but unfortunately it didn't seem to matter